# SSL failure fallback

Tags: apache-http-server, ssl, public-key

I've successfully configured my Apache webserver to make use of public certificates as an authentication method, using following configuration:

```
SSLVerifyClient require
SSLVerifyDepth 1
SSLCACertificateFile /etc/ssl/private/key.crt
```

When the client has no client installed, however, I'd like to redirect them to another (error) page, instead of showing them the standard (cryptological) error message:

```
ssl_error_handshake_failure_alert
```

I googled around and found someone who developed an mod_ssl_error module, which requires to recompile the mod_ssl module, obviously. As there is no real connection made (as it's aborted), Apache can't display any error message.

Another way to do this, would be to set the SSLVerifyClient directive to optional, and check whether the user accessed the page using a public key. Is there any way of verifying this?

Is there any (good) way to achieve something like this?

Answer (score 0):

I've found a nice solution using PHP (a language which I was using anyway):

http://cweiske.de/tagebuch/ssl-client-certificates.htm

Comment: Link-only answers are definitely frowned upon in these places. To improve the answer, make sure that it would still provide most of its value even if the site you linked to ceases to exist, and distill the core of the 10000 words you linked to to a lot fewer words.